# Difficulty with proving or refuting a claim related to a recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, proof-writing, induction

I am trying to prove a certain claim about a recursive sequence.
The sequence is defined as follows:

$$
S_{n}^{k}(a) = 
\begin{cases} 
\sqrt{a} & \text{if } n = 1, \quad a \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, \, a \neq 1 \\
\sum_{i=1}^{k} \sqrt{d_i} & \text{if } n > 1, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}
\end{cases}
$$

where $d_i$ represents the $i$-th digit of the previous term $S_{n-1}^{k}(a)$, and $k$ represents the number of digits of $S_{n-1}^{k}(a)$ from which we extract and sum the square roots.

**The claim:** $\forall a$, when $k \geq 17$, $S_{n}^{k}(a) = S_{n}^{k+m}(a)$, where $m \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

My question would be: How would I go on to prove or disprove this claim? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

*(I am not a native English speaker, so I might be using the incorrect terms).*

Comment: You've defined a sequence whose elements you call $S_n^k(a)$, but then you've asked about $\mathcal{O}_n^k(a)$. Are those intended to be the same thing?

Comment: The entries in your sequence are (in general) irrational numbers. Exactly which $k$ digits are you extracting from each?

Comment: You will probably find the following useful to think about: what are all the possible values of any $S_n^k(a)$?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yes, those were indeed intended to be the same thing. I've corrected it.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan To compute $S_{n}^{k}(a)$, we take the first $k$ digits of $S_{n-1}^{k}(a)$. For example, if $S_{n-1}^{k}(a)$ = 1.73205081 and k = 4, then $S_{n}^{k}(a)$ = sqrt(1)
 + sqrt(7) + sqrt(3) + sqrt(2) The first 4 digits of $S_{n-1}^{k}$. 

I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Yup, it does. So, my suggestion to you is that you think about what possible values $S_n^k(a)$ can take. How many are there?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I would say that the possible values of $S_{n}^{k}(a)$ depend on the initial value $a$ and the number of digits $k$, right? Depening on those values, it changes the behavior and values of the sequence.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I have written a script that plots the sequence given a certain $a$ and $k$. I think that might be very useful here?

Comment: In general, that sort of computation is a very good thing to do. In this particular case, I think it will be less helpful than you might hope. The _actual_ values the $S$ take will depend on $a$ and $k$ -- but can you say something about _all the possible values_ you could imagine them taking?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Theoretically, the number of possible values the sequence can take is infinite due to its recursive nature and the infinite combinations of parameters $a$ and $k$.

Comment: Suppose we fix the value of $k$. Is the number of possible values still infinite?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yes, the number of possible values will remain infinite. If the claim is correct, the variation in $k$ does not contribute to an infinite number of possible values once $k$ exceeds or equals 17.

If the claim is incorrect, the number of possible values is still infinite aswell.

Comment: The value of $S_n^k(a)$ is a sum with $k$ terms. What possible values does each term have?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Sorry for the misunderstanding. Each term has a possible value of 0 to 9. When $k < 17$, increasing $k$ might introduce new digits from the previous term. When $k ≥ 17$, it is very likely that all the digits have been used already, making it so that the sequence stabilizes?

I am not a 100% sure why the stabilization occurs at $k = 17$.

Comment: The point isn't so much "all the digits have been used already". Are you familiar with the usual proof that rational numbers have repeating decimal expansions?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yes, I am somewhat familiar with that proof.

In the proof it is observed that the repeating pattern arises due to a finite set of remainders when dividing by the denominator. Similarly, with the claim, the stability arises because of the finite set of possibilities for the square root of digits.

Comment: Right! Finitely many digits, finitely many possibilities for each digit, so finitely many possible sums, so eventually periodic. I haven't thought through why $k=17$ is enough, but that seems like it shouldn't be too hard with a bit of attention to detail...

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know why it took so long for me to connect the dots...